# Failed to lookup view with Express + jade + angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug

Like so many before me I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to lookup view "/partials/test" in views directory    "/home/aveline/git/multivision/server/views"
```

Since I am using Jade, my templates get rendered through app.get (this is my server.js file):

```
var express = require('express'), 
stylus = require('stylus'),
logger = require('morgan'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

function compile(str, path){
   return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('view engine','jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(stylus.middleware(
    {
        src: __dirname + '/public',
        compile: compile
    }
));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/partials/:partialPath',function(req, res){
    res.render('/partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

var port = 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port " + port);
```

The thing is, this template "test.jade" is actually here in that directory. So when I go to localhost:3030 (the port I listen to), i get this error (full-stack):

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/partials/test" in views directory "/home/aveline/git/multivision/server/views"
at Function.app.render (/home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:485:17)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:7)
at Object.port [as handle] (/home/aveline/git/multivision/server.js:27:6)
at next_layer (/home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:113:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:117:5)
at /home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:222:24
at param (/home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:307:14)
at param (/home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:323:14)
at Function.proto.process_params (/home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:367:3)
at next (/home/aveline/git/multivision/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:216:19)
```

Could anyone help me with this? I have tried several other solutions on other threads but none worked so far.

If you need more code samples, please say so in the comments.

EDIT: I found the solution, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that to fix this, I had to remove the / before partials in the res.render() bit. The full path that it was searching for was /home/aveline/git/multivision/server/views//partials/test

Solution:

```
app.get('/partials/:partialPath',function(req, res){
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});
```